# count ins sql and display it console

Tags: c#, sql, count

I just want to count the data in my table but I cant do it when ever I call the method it will automatically add new data instead of counting rows in the table. Help me how to display it in console.

```
public void countt()
{
    setcData(new ArrayList< Notification>());

    try 
    {
        super.getConnectToDbHost();
        PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement ("select count(lastname) from reserve ");

        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next())
        {
            // int idl = rs.getInt("id");
            String sum=rs.getString("count(lastname)");

               // Process data here
        }

        rs.close();
        statement.close();
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What language is your example? I guess it's C#. The next time pointing in the tag programming language and system that you use, such as `SQL`, for others to see your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using aliases:

```
"select count(lastname) as nr_results from reserve"

// ...

int sum=rs.getInt("nr_results);
```

it should work fine.